# XSLT: Control call-templaterecursion depending upon recursion result

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have an XSLT with recursion and I call the recursion within a for-each loop

```
<xsl:for-each select="$ChildList">
    <!-- Get the new elNodeList here and recurse -->
    <xsl:variable name="inp" select="current()"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="NewNode" select="/node()/pro:simple_instance[pro:name=$inp]"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="uniqueNode" select="$NewNode/pro:name except ($BeatenPath)"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="count($uniqueNode) > 0"> 
        <xsl:call-template name="Recurse2Find">
            <xsl:with-param name="AppNode" select="$AppNode"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="elNode" select="$NewNode"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="thisProduct" select="$thisProduct"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="BeatenPath" select="$BeatenPath|$NewNode/pro:name"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="rev" select="$rev+1"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="Found" select="0"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am basically searching for something in a graph and I go down one level of the graph in each recursion while I follow different legs of the graph in each iteration in the `for-each` loop.

If I find the item I am searchin for in any of the leg, I wish to stop searching further for that root.

I can return a value from the call-template, but do not know how to implement it and put it as a parameter further. The parameter `Found` in the template will play otherwise. If I can update the value of the parameter from the earlier recursion, it will help me. But how can I do it?

**EDIT:**

I am adding some XML elements that build up the source XML here:

```
<simple_instance>
    <name>KB_249702_Class31</name>
    <type>Technology_Build_Architecture</type>
    <own_slot_value>
        <slot_reference>contained_architecture_components</slot_reference>
        <value value_type="simple_instance">KB_249702_Class32</value>
        <value value_type="simple_instance">KB_181699_Class96</value>
        <value value_type="simple_instance">KB_181699_Class97</value>
        <value value_type="simple_instance">KB_692833_Class51</value>
        <value value_type="simple_instance">KB_692833_Class52</value>
    </own_slot_value>
    <own_slot_value>
        <slot_reference>contained_provider_architecture_relations</slot_reference>
        <value value_type="simple_instance">KB_181699_Class98</value>
        <value value_type="simple_instance">KB_692833_Class54</value>
        <value value_type="simple_instance">KB_692833_Class55</value>
    </own_slot_value>
    <own_slot_value>
        <slot_reference>describes_technology_provider</slot_reference>
        <value value_type="simple_instance">KB_249702_Class30</value>
    </own_slot_value>
    <own_slot_value>
        <slot_reference>name</slot_reference>
        <value value_type="string">HHS Modernization Arch::Product_Architecture</value>
    </own_slot_value>
</simple_instance>
```

I am looking for some key like `KB_249702_Class30` and I start from some root. The root is an element like this with `<type>Application_Provider</type>` and look at all the `<own_slot_value>` where I get `<value value_type="simple_instance">` and pick up the value. If I do not find, I go to the element with `<name>..</name>` with the value. I continue the search in this manner.

Comment: Please, provide a complete (but small) source XML, the wanted result, and explain what the transformation should do. This is what makes a problem defined. I would be glad to provide a solution, given all this necessary information.

Comment: Also, what is a "leg"? I haven't seen such a term in graph theory. Do you mean a path? Is the graph directed or undirected? Please, provide an instance of the graph (small) xml representation.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Basically at any instance, there are multiple relations from each node leading to different nodes. I am describing each path starting from a node to the connected nodes as a "leg".

Comment: @Kanghan: This is still a mystery. Do you mean a "leg" is just an "arc"?

Comment: @Kanghan: This question is too-general without a specific example/instance of a graph representation and without providing a wanted result. I generally don't spend time on such "question". The lack of detail usually means that the asker doesn't know what they are asking... Please, improve this question if you want people to provide useful, working solutions.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I have updated the question with some sample source data. I understand that the question is a bit generic and this is because, the structure/schema of the XML is not understood well. I am trying to find some pattern to find what I am looking for. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Kangkan, what is "essential viewer" and how is it relevant to this question?  It is not mentioned in the question body, the comments or answers.

Comment: @Kangkan: This is a good first step forward. Now, please, provide the exact wanted output. Also, from your newest edit it seems that you are describing an XML document that is different from the provided one. Please, correct. It is a good idea to try to come up with the simplest possible (minimalistic) but complete example, that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: What I presented in the XML is a piece from the provided one. The XML is an output from Protege (http://www.enterprise-architecture.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value of **Recurse2Find** template in a variable **RecurseResult**

```
<xsl:variable name="RecurseResult">
    <xsl:call-template name="Recurse2Find">
        <!-- Do your stuff -->
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

## EDIT:

Note: Since I have less time, haven't tested this.

Follow this steps for implementing:-

**Step 1:** Declare a Param variable with dummy value on top

```
<xsl:param name="rResult" select="0" />
```

**Step 2:** After storing the value in **RecurseResult** variable

```
  <xsl:variable name="RecurseResult">
     <xsl:call-template name="Recurse2Find">
          <xsl:with-param name="temp" select="$rResult"/>
          <!-- Do your stuff -->
     </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable> 

  Note: for the first time, rResult has dummy value.
```

**Step 3:** Pass the **RecurseResult** variable value to one more call template **ParamUpdate** for updating the param variable **rResult**.

```
<xsl:call-template name="ParamUpdate">
    <xsl:with-param name="temp" select="$RecurseResult"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

**Step 4:** Call template will update the param variable as follows.

```
<xsl:template name="ParamUpdate">
    <xsl:param name="temp" />
    <xsl:param name="rResult" select="$temp"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I feel this should work. Try this and let me know.

Comment: But How can I pass it in the next recursion to the same template?

Comment: @kangkan: I have updated my answer. I feel this will help you. Try this and let me know..

Comment: No positive result. This does not yield.